# En React como hago para renderizar etiqutas html que vienen en una variable en forma de string

Tags: javascript, html, json, reactjs, api

Recibo desde un API un Array de objetos y uno de los elementos del array contiene N cantidad de etiquetas html con su contenido y todo incluyendo imagenes, h2, h3 p, etc, pero esto viene en forma de string, un solo string con todo este contenido

[image: Como hago para renderizar esta cadena en codigo html (en react)]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como hago para renderizar esta cadena en codigo html (en react)

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39758136/render-html-string-as-real-html-in-a-react-component

Comment: Debes obtener la ref de un div por ejemplo y cambiar el innerhtml. un div sera el que mostrara eso con su innerhtml

Answer (score 1):

[image: Code Sandbox]

```
dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: variableHTML}}
```

Espero te sirva de algo.
Creo que esta practica no es muy recomendada.